# Azure Storage Blob Policy to enforce ClientSideEncryptionVersion.V2_0

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

i updated my application because of this [security vulnerability](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-storage-blog/ga-azure-storage-updating-client-side-encryption-in-sdk-to/ba-p/3563013).

Is it possible to set a policy in Azure Storage Blob that only blobs without encryption or with ClientSideEncryptionVersion.V2_0 can be uploaded?
Upload attempts with ClientSideEncryptionVersion.V1_0 should be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have this feature today. You may leave your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/79b1327d-d925-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f06a4) All the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

Client side encryption can be done only using SDK because we use CEK to encrypt the data before uploading, so you have to write your own custom logic for this scenario, Also make sure that all your application are upgraded to latest SDK.

Alternatively, would it be possible to use the Azure Metric Explorer to evaluate the upload attempts with the ClientSideEncryptionVersion?
No. Encryption metadata is stored with the blob, but we don’t have granular tracking for what metadata is set.

Or can you alternatively, for example, give a tag or an application version when uploading that is saved together with the blob?
This is completely dependent on the application and the features you use in storage/the SDK. There isn’t anything automatically enabled by the SDK.

Please let me know if you have any further queries.

Comment: Alternatively, would it be possible to use the Azure Metric Explorer to evaluate the upload attempts with the ClientSideEncryptionVersion?
Or can you alternatively, for example, give a tag or an application version when uploading that is saved together with the blob?
Unfortunately, we cannot prevent someone from making an upload with an older client.